# how to create a SwiftUI or SceneKit Controller similar to Blender Axis Controller

Tags: swiftui, scenekit, metal

I want to create a controller for an axis similar to Blender either using SwiftUI or SceneKit
[image: Axis Control]

Drag Gestures to rotate the axis and viewport of the SceneKit Grid Section. Is there any better way to handle it in SwiftUI or do I have to implement it using SceneKit Node representation?